# Change the file name cut (3 dots) in Xcode 12 tab

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode12

As you can see in the image below, when I am opening a lot of tabs in Xcode 12 it cuts the file name in the middle and adds 3 dots.

[image]

Is there any chance to let it show the full file name or at least cut the end of the file and not the middle ?

Thank you.